# I need to sort Java lists or xml lists automatically

Tags: java, list, sorting, xslt

I have many xml structures with lists like

```
<a>
<b>
<list1>
<item>Paris</item>
<item>London</item>
<item>Berlin</item>
<item>Zurich</item>
</list1>
</b>
<list2>
<item>Butter</item>
<item>Sugar</item>
<item>Flower</item>
<item>Eggs</item>
</list2>
<list2>
<item>0.1</item>
<item>20.0</item>
<item>10.0</item>
<item>0.01</item>
</list2>
</a>
```

I want xslt function, that automatically sorts **every** list regardless of the name by name or by number in ascending order. I do not want to specifically mention the names of the lists. It should also not mention where the list is in the hierarchy.

I did not find anything. I expect the lists to be sorted in ascending order.

Comment: How would you define a "list"? And what if some items in the same list are numbers and others are strings?

Answer (score 2):

Generic stylesheets are difficult to write. Try perhaps something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[* and not(*/*)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="number(*[1]) = number(*[1])">
                <xsl:apply-templates>
                    <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates>
                    <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This looks for elements with only leaf nodes as child elements. It then tests if the first child is a number; if so, the child elements are sorted numerically, otherwise as text.